# Deploy script needs to update an integer in a config file

Tags: perl, unix, command-line, sed

I'm working on a python fabric script that eases my solution deployment on different environments.

It works great so far, but I have at the end of the script a prompt that ask me if I want to edit a .yml config file, basically, to update my assets version. I go manually through vim inside and basically increment that number:

```
  reconnection_delay: 50
  max_attempts: 500
  assets_version: 5360
```

How could I possibly automatically do that only with command line. Should use sed or perl it seems, but I'm not familiar with that, and some help might be appreciated here!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -i.backup -pe 's{ ( \b assets_version: \s+ ) (\d+) $ }{ $1 . ( 1 + $2 ) }xmse;' your.yml
```

This will make a copy of *your.yml* named *your.yml.backup*, look for the line containing "assets_version:" and increment the number by 1.

Answer (score 3):

sed doesn't have any built-in way to do arithmetic, so it's not easy to do.

**perl**

Besides doing proper yaml parsing, you might get away with a one-liner like this:

```
perl -anE '$, = " "; $F[1]++ if $F[0] =~ /assets_version/; say @F'
```

The `-a` switch splits the input into the `@F` array, which gives access to the fields.

**sed**

GNU sed can call external programs, so with the help of bc you could do it like this:

```
/assets_version/ {
  h                                      # save line to hold space
  s/[^:]+:\s*(.*)/echo \1 + 1 | bc/e     # convert line to 'echo num + 1 | bc'
                                         # and pass on to /bin/sh
  G                                      # append hold space to pattern space
  s/([^\n]+)\n([^:]+).*/\2: \1/          # reorder to replace with incremented
                                         # number
}'
```

The same on one line:

```
sed -r '/assets_version/ { h; s/[^:]+:\s*(.*)/echo \1 + 1 | bc/e; G; s/([^\n]+)\n([^:]+).*/\2: \1/ }'
```

If you're wondering how to do it with pure sed, here's one way inspired by the `cat -n` example in the GNU sed manual (works with BSD sed as well):

*inc.sed*

```
/assets_version/ { 
  h;                                                  # save for later
  s/[^:]+:\s*//;                                      # only keep number
  /^9*$/ s/^/0/;                                      # need one more number
  s/.9*$/_&/;                                         # mark what will change
                                                      # when incrementing
  H;                                                  # save for later
  s/^.*_//;                                           # only keep what will
                                                      # change
  y/0123456789/1234567890/;                           # transliterate numbers
  G;                                                  # append hold space
  s/([^\n]+)\n([^:]+:\s*)[^\n]+\n([^_]*).*/\2\3\1/;   # reorder to get result
}
```

Note, this only works with non-negative integers.

With GNU sed, run it like this:

```
sed -r -f inc.sed infile
```

BSD sed:

```
sed -E -f inc.sed infile
```

Output in all cases:

```
reconnection_delay: 50
max_attempts: 500
assets_version: 5361
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/assets_version/{$NF++}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

just looks for the assets_version and increments the last field on the line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use YAML tiny (or other modules like: YAML::XS, YAML::Syck ) to read and write the YAML file.

https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Tiny

```
use YAML::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;
# Create a YAML file
my $yaml = YAML::Tiny->new;
#check what the content
print Dumper($yaml);
# Open the config
$yaml = YAML::Tiny->read( 'file.yml' );
# Changing data
#$yaml->[0]->{section} = { this => 'that' };
$yaml->[0]->{reconnection_delay} = 50;
$yaml->[0]->{max_attempts} = 500;
$yaml->[0]->{assets_version} = $yaml->{assets_version} + 1;

# Save the file
$yaml->write( 'file.yml' );
```